# XML / PHP - Extracting information from multiple document nodes

Tags: php, xml

I was wondering if someone could help me out with some code.

I have a KML ( Google Earth XML ) which im trying to import into my application.

The problem im having is that when extracting the data, it works perfect up until the first  node thing and wont process the rest of the file.

The KML file is massive so i will show a sample below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Folder>
    <name>Kalamunda</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Document>
        <name>Export 1418786594.kml</name>
        <Placemark>
            <name>76-122 Tourist Drive 207</name>
            <description>Kalamunda WA 6076</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>116.072723865509,-31.98064436184923,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>76-122 Tourist Drive 207</name>
            <description>Kalamunda WA 6076</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>116.0731288790703,-31.98067621355563,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>76-122 Tourist Drive 207</name>
            <description>Kalamunda WA 6076</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>116.0735687613487,-31.98064436184923,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>12 Hinkler Rd</name>
            <description>Kalamunda WA 6076</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>116.0740676522255,-31.98083319680418,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
    <Document>
        <name>Export 1418785221.kml</name>
        <Placemark>
            <name>LOT 435 Collins Rd</name>
            <description>Kalamunda WA 6076</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>116.0624188184738,-31.97887202447751,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>25 Central Rd</name>
            <description>Kalamunda WA 6076</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>116.0589158535004,-31.9744125903374,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>49 Canning Rd</name>
            <description>Kalamunda WA 6076</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>116.0574942827225,-31.97629422494352,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>13 Anne Ave</name>
            <description>Walliston WA 6076</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>116.0673272609711,-31.99400063250859,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
    <Document>
        <name>Export 1418783501.kml</name>
        <Placemark>
            <name>3 Lookout Rd</name>
            <description>Kalamunda WA 6076</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>116.037417948246,-31.98043960061557,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>9 Ozone Terrace</name>
            <description>Kalamunda WA 6076</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>116.0382279753685,-31.98028261669366,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</Folder>
</kml>
```

The code im using is as follows:

```
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $xml_data->Folder->Document->Placemark as $placemark ) {

        $data[$i][] = $placemark->name;
        $data[$i][] = $placemark->description;

        list($x, $y) = explode(',', $placemark->Point->coordinates);
        $data[$i][] = array($x, $y);

        $i++;

    }
```

Using this code, it will extract the data up until the 12 Hinkler Rd placemark, I think because there is a closing  tag, it wont go any further.

How would i go about extracting all the data given an XML in this format?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: It is the `Placemark`s you are interested in - name, description, coordinates?

Comment: Yes @MichaelBerkowski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the `<Placemark>` nodes are most easily obtained with an XPath query. Since the are under the `kml` namespace, you can query for `//kml:Placemark`.  The `//` will search for the expression `Placemark` at any level in the XML.

We can considerably simplify the inner workings of the loop you had originally, with clever use of [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) in conjunction with the `explode()` you already had. Nesting `explode()` inside `array_slice()`, retrieving the first two coordinate components and discarding the third (`,0`) can happen all in one action and immediately assign them to an array key `['coordinates']`.

Also, instead of maintaining an  incrementing `$i`, you may [use the `[]` array append syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) to just stick a new sub-array onto the `$data` collection array directly.

```
// Query all <Placemark> elements at once
$placemarks = $xml_data->xpath('//kml:Placemark');
// Loop over them and construct an array of child properties

$data = array();
foreach ($placemarks as $mark) {
  // Collect the properties into a new array and append
  // that to $data with []
  $data[] = array(
    // Cast SimpleXML elements to strings with (string)
    'name' => (string)$mark->name,
    'description' => (string)$mark->description,
    // Get the coords in one action - explode on the ','
    // but return only the first two elements via array_slice()
    'coordinates' => array_slice(explode(',', $mark->Point->coordinates), 0, 2)
  );
}
print_r($data);
// Displays:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 76-122 Tourist Drive 207
            [description] => Kalamunda WA 6076
            [coordinates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 116.072723865509
                    [1] => -31.98064436184923
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 76-122 Tourist Drive 207
            [description] => Kalamunda WA 6076
            [coordinates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 116.0731288790703
                    [1] => -31.98067621355563
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 76-122 Tourist Drive 207
            [description] => Kalamunda WA 6076
            [coordinates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 116.0735687613487
                    [1] => -31.98064436184923
                )

        )
    ... SNIP.... 
    ... SNIP.... 
    ... SNIP....    
    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => 3 Lookout Rd
            [description] => Kalamunda WA 6076
            [coordinates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 116.037417948246
                    [1] => -31.98043960061557
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => 9 Ozone Terrace
            [description] => Kalamunda WA 6076
            [coordinates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 116.0382279753685
                    [1] => -31.98028261669366
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that .. I am getting an error saying unexpected [ on the line that has $data = [];

Comment: You must not have PHP 5.4. Use `$data = array().` instead. Likewise in the loop  you'll need `$data[] = array(...)` instead of `$data[] = [...]`  Darn - this was probably the first time I used 5.4+ array syntax in an answer, hoping the install base was finally high enough :-(

Comment: @BigJobbies I just edited to convert it back to old style `array()` declarations.  Someday, I guess...